# Change bottomnavigatinview style as picture

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, bottomnavigationview

I want imitate the menu as saw in picture.

Tried by using compile 'com.github.armcha:SpaceNavigationView:1.6.0' but is old and don't wanna change all entire code of my default activity with bottom navigation view.

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      />
    <!--   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"-->



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rett_arr_blu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

bottom_nav_menu.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_news" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_mappa"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_mappa" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_convenzioni"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_convention"
        android:title="@string/title_convenzioni" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_altro"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_altro"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        android:title="@string/title_altro" />

</menu>
```

Result must be as picture in this repository: armcha/Space-Navigation-View. Search by google and find it...

Comment: nobody knows :( ?